# Inserção com relacionamento N:N

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho esses inputs text, de certa forma as pessoas podem escolher preenche-los ou não. Ou apenas preencher alguns deles. 
Eu envio os dados desse formulário via axios em uma array(não sei se é a melhor maneira, por isso estou aqui fazendo esse post).
Explicando mais, esse formulário seria os impostos(`Taxes`) que faz parte de um formulário de produtos(`Products`).

E pra isso eu crie 3 tabelas no laravel. Uma tabela para `Products`, outra para os `Taxes_names` uma tabela pivot, relacionando o id de ambos mas com um campo a mais, que no caso é o `value`, que armazenaria o valor colocado nesses input text.

No laravel, eu faço um request dessa array da seguinte forma.

```
$taxes = $request -> taxes;
```

A relação está montada e correta. Eu consigo inserir os dados via banco tranquilo e fazer um debug, etc.

Tabela pivot `product_taxes`:
id | product_id |taxes_id

Digamos que na tabela `taxes_name` tenha os seguintes dados:

```
id | name |
-----------------------
1  | cfop |
2  | cst/csosn icms|
3  | cst pis(danfe)|
4  | cst cofins(danfe)|
```

Meu problema é, como eu vou puxar os ids corretamente dessa tabela e passar para a tabela pivot, junto com esses forms preenchidos.

Model da class `Products`:

```
public function taxes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\TaxesNames', 'product_taxes', 'product_id', 'taxes_id')->withPivot('value');

}
```

Array recebida no laravel

```
array (
    'cfop' => '12',
    'cst' => '2',
    'cstPis' => '3',
    'cstCofins' => '4',
  )
```

axios:

```
           this.axios.post('http://chart.solutions/public/api/produto', {
                nome: this.nome, 
                codigo: this.codigo, 
                preco: this.preco,
                group: this.selectedgroup,
                subgroup: this.selectedsubgroup,
                taxes: this.taxes
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.data.success){
                    this.clearForm()
                    this.productSwal("success")
                    console.log(this.taxes)
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                    this.productSwal("error") 
            });
```

Comment: Bem, o que você está fazendo para inserir os dados? Cadê a camada de transporte (no seu caso, o código do Axios   que você está usando)?

Comment: Então, eu envio esses dados como um array. Editei o post aqui e postei como o laravel recebe essa array. Alias, eu consigo simplesmente pegar a "key" separado do valor nessa array? Se eu conseguir, provavelmente eu tenho uma parada na cabeça pra resolver esse problema. Eu acho que eu puxo o nome dele, procuro na db e retorno o id, e por aí vai.

Comment: Cadê o Axios? Precisa colocar também no código.

Comment: editado. Eu achei uma solução, talvez não muito viavel. Eu pego as keys dessa array, e procuro ela no banco com um where. Em seguida eu pego o id e acho que é isso.